# Reversing an Array: Please check this code out

Tags: java, arrays

I am struggling to understand why the following code cannot reverse an array.
I have made a copy of the array. 
As you can see below, I have used a for loop and started the counter from 0 until the array's length. I set the first element of the original array to be equal with the last. And, the second from the beginning of the array to be equal with the second from the end. And, so on.
But the result gives me back the original array, not the reversed one.

I have pasted the whole code here so you can copy it into your IDE. Please help me figure this out.

Thank you very much in advance.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    
    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] myArray = normal(5);
        reverse(myArray);
    }
    
    public static int[] normal(int count){
        int [] array = new int[count];
        
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            array[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        return array;
    }
    
    public static void reverse(int[] array){
        int[] reverse = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
        
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            array[i] = reverse[(array.length - i)-1];
    }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(reverse));
    }    
}
```

Comment: You are printing the `reverse` array, which is a copy of the original array. The reversed array is `array`.

Comment: Hint: Print out `myArray` in your `main method` after `reverse(myArray);` and you'll see that your code does reverse an array. Just not the array you expect it to.

Comment: Sir @Eran, already gave you the answer.

Comment: Oh my! You were right! I am a newbie. Sorry for bothering to ask such a simple question. But I have embedded the "System.out.println(reverse)" already in the "reverse method". So why doesn't automatically printout the reversed?

Comment: @M.Steiner because your code `reverse(myArray);` from your main method has reverted your array back to the original array due to this `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(reverse));`, in which it should have been `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing reverse-

Replace this line

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(reverse));
```

with this

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is the culprit

```java
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(reverse));
```

Replace it with

```java
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

A better way to interpret the result would be to use something similar

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] myArray = normal(5);
        System.out.println("Before reverse");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
        reverse(myArray);
        System.out.println("After reverse");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
}
```

and remove the print statements from the recursive loop completely.